# VBA Error BC30452 Operator 'Mod' is not defined for types 'Char' and 'Integer'

Tags: vb.net

the following code is getting the above error and i cant see why. i know the mod operator needs numbers in front and behind it so chrArray(i) is not getting a number.  any help appreciated.

Public Class Form1

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Application.Exit()
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Textbox1.Text = ""
    Textbox2.Text = ""
End Sub


Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim sNumber As String
    sNumber = TextBox1.Text

    Textbox2.Text = EvenDigitMessage(sNumber)
End Sub


Private Function IsOnlyNumber(ByVal qty As String) As Boolean
    Dim objRegExp As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("^\d+$")
    Return objRegExp.Match(qty).Success
End Function

Private Function IsThreeDigitNumber(ByVal num As String) As Boolean
    Dim objRegExp As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("^\d{3}$")
    Return objRegExp.Match(num).Success
End Function

Private Function EvenDigitMessage(ByVal sNumber As String) As String
    Dim bValidDigits As Boolean
    Dim bValidNumber As Boolean
    Dim sMessage As String
    Dim iTotalEven As Integer = 0

    If Not IsNumeric(sNumber) Then
        sMessage = "Please enter a 3 digit number"
    Else

        bValidNumber = IsOnlyNumber(sNumber)
        bValidDigits = IsThreeDigitNumber(sNumber)

        If bValidNumber = False Or bValidDigits = False Then
            sMessage = "Please enter a 3 digit number"
        Else
            iTotalEven = CountEvenDigits(sNumber)
            sMessage = "This number contains" & iTotalEven & "even digits."
        End If

    End If

    Return sMessage
End Function

Private Function CountEvenDigits(ByVal sNumber As String) As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim chrArray() As Char
    Dim iTotal As Integer = 0


    chrArray = sNumber.ToCharArray


    For i = 0 To chrArray.Length - 1
        If chrArray(i) Mod 2 = 0 Then
            If iTotal = 0 Then
                iTotal = 1
            Else
                iTotal = iTotal + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next

    Return iTotal
End Function
```

End Class

Comment: In C# you'd cast it: If (int)chrArray(i) Mod 2 = 0 Then

Comment: Option Strict Off allowed these kind of shenanigans.  But Char is new in VB.NET and using the Mod operator on a character makes very little sense since it is not a sensibly ordered type in Unicode.  Expect a "huh?" from a Chinese user :)  You have to use AscW(chrArray(i)) to convince the compiler you know what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

Base on this linke
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7sx7t66b.aspx

Visual Basic does not convert directly between Char and the numeric types. You can use the Asc or AscW function to convert a Char value to an Integer that represents its code point. You can use the Chr or ChrW function to convert an Integer value to a Char that has that code point.
If the type checking switch (Option Strict Statement) is on, you must append the literal type character to a single-character string literal to identify it as the Char data type. The following example illustrates this.

so you have to change your code to somthing like this

```
If Asc(chrArray(i)) Mod 2 = 0 Then
    If iTotal = 0 Then
            iTotal = 1
        Else
            iTotal = iTotal + 1
        End If
End If
```